# Bootstrap in Android application using android studio

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, android-studio-2.0

I'm new to Android application. I don't know how to create responsive design application using Android Studio. In my application the layout will be changed based on the content what I gave. I didn't get the proper alignment.
Here are my issues:

Alignment of my layout is good:
[image]

I gave same layout at first, but alignment changes:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can tryout [this library.](https://github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap)

> Android Bootstrap is an Android library which provides custom views styled according to the Twitter Bootstrap Specification. This allows you to spend more time on development rather than trying to get a consistent theme across your app, especially if you are already familiar with the Bootstrap Framework.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but am not familiar with bootstrap framework how can i overcome this issue?

Comment: this library was inspired from the concepts of bootstrap (according to the Twitter Bootstrap Specification). I think that's what you were looking for.